# Switching through different versions of GHC included 7.0.4

Tags: haskell, ghc, haskell-stack

I need to compile some code starting from the GHC version 7.0.4 until the most recent 8.0.2.
I know that using `stack` I can do something like:

`stack init --resolver lts ...`

on the local project but the `lts` versions don't go further than GHC 7.8.3.

How can I switch back to older version of GHC without using `stack`?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot have stack use ghc 7.0.4 because it's not in their snapshot. The oldest compiler stack supports is 7.8.3.

Theoretically, stack can provide support for older compilers, but the [Stackage server](https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2014/08/announcing-stackage-server) was announced at August, 2014 and GHC 7.0.4 was [released on June, 2011](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/download_ghc_7_0_4.html). That's my educated guess of why 7.0.4 is not present.

If you want your code to have support for older compilers, I would recommend you to use a [CI system like Travis](https://github.com/psibi/download/blob/master/.travis.yml). Another alternative if you are using a Ubuntu machine is to use [Herber's PPA](https://launchpad.net/~hvr/+archive/ubuntu/ghc) for installing the older compilers.

Comment: so I can switch back to older versions?

Comment: @Randomize If it's for testing, I would suggest you to [use a CI system like Travis](https://github.com/psibi/download/blob/master/.travis.yml) for supporting old compilers. If you still want to install locally, the only way to do is download the old compiler from [here](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/download.html) and try doing it. But it will be a slightly painful process.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need stack to build the project, i.e. `stack.yaml` and `stack build`?

If it is not the case and you just want multiple ghc versions, you might want to try

1. **nix**, it have various ghc [versions](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/tree/master/pkgs/development/compilers/ghc).

But keep in mind that older than 8.0.2 is not officially [support](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/26468#issuecomment-311724007) but it might still working.

2. **docker**, use it to setup any version you want
3. **travis**, as previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44999591/1664572) suggested.